# How can I get string from csv file instead of list?

Tags: python, csv

I want to search for a pattern(e.g "0,22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41") in the CSV file (e.g Lavender,22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41) and get the name(Lavender). But I can't use any 're' module functions, because CSV file give a list of elements(e.g "['Albus', '15', '49', '38', '5', '14', '44', '14', '12']").

Here is part of code:

```
first = []
other = ''
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as data:
    dataread = csv.reader(data)
    first = next(dataread)
    first.pop(0)
    for row in dataread:
        other += str(row)
```

I tried to convert it to string with '' and str, but it still shows those brackets.

```
    pattern = re.compile(rf'([a-zA-Z]+),({maxStr})')
result = re.search(pattern, other)
if result:
    print(result.group(1))
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: Why don't you just open the file and read it line by line?

Comment: As @MilesDavis says like so `with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csvfile: csvtext = csvfile.readlines()` or as a whole string `with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csvfile: csvtext = csvfile.readl()`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvtext = csvfile.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use join.

see here the add of *join* instead of  *other += str(row)*

```py
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as data:
    dataread = csv.reader(data)
    first = next(dataread)
    first.pop(0)
    for row in dataread:
        other = ', '.join(row)
```

*Other* is returning a string from which you can "re" it.